# How do ISPs configure a static ip in a double nat?

Tags: nat, ip-address

So I have an ISP which I requested a static ip. My ISP gives a static ip for a one time payment. So I decided to get one. My ISP does double NAT which by default all incoming tcp ports are blocked. But then how come I have a static public ip with open ports when my ISP does double nat? I tried thinking hard how can that be possible. So I decided to get help here.

Comment: As far as I know, ISPs are only doing this for residential networks, not for your business. You ask about your home network on [su].

Answer (score 2):

When you've got a public IPv4 address there's no reason for your ISP to NAT (external to your network) - it would defy the purpose of a public IP in the first place.

Using a static, public IP on your external router interface doesn't open any ports on that router. You'll need to port forward/DNAT any services you'd want exposed to the Internet on your own NAT router and configure your firewall appropriately.

Comment: yes I know tha5 but when I tracery to google the connection is sent to some private ip address 10.xx.xx.xx on the second hop. And also my router settings say that my ip is 10.xx.xx.xx. So I definitely think that I am behind nat. I am just surprised that port forwarding works on my router even when behind a nat.

Comment: Your local PC address is most likely a private one. Your router's got two addresses: an internal (in the same subnet as your PC) and an external - the latter is usually public but can also be private with CGNAT. In case it's private you can't port forward anything without support by the ISP. Whether are not any private IPs show up on a public traceroute doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

"double NAT" is not an industry standard term, but from your description and your comment it seems your ISP use Carrier Grade NAT (CGN) as defined in [RFC 6598](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598).

In this case the ISP provides to your router a "CGN" IP address (either an RFC1918 address or an address from 100.64.0.0/10) and then perform NAT in its network to a globally routable (I.E. public) IP address.

In order to assign you a static IP address it has to configure an inbound NAT rule (I.E. forwarding) for all traffic sent to the public IP address that was assigned to you to the CGN IP address of your router (which is likely fixed).